# Finding center of mass of a solid with non-uniform density

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the center of mass of the solid $$ R = {(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 \leq 1^2, 0 \leq z \leq \frac \pi2 }$$ if the density is given by $$\rho(x,y,z) = 5\bigg(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + sin(z)\bigg). $$

First i tried solving for the mass with the triple integral $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \int_0^15r\big(r+sin(z)\big) = \frac{10\pi^2}{6}  $$ Which gave me the $z$ coordinate $\frac{3+\pi}{\pi}$ Not sure if this is correct though. Also, i don't know how to find the other coordinates now seeing as the density is not uniform.

Comment: set up is ok but check the derivation, by wolfy the mass should be different https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+5r(r%2Bsin+z)drdzdt+r%3D0..1,+z%3D0..pi%2F2,+t%3D0..2pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the method is correct since $\rho(x,y,z)$ is symmetric with respect to z axis the center of mass has coordinates $(0,0,z_G)$ with (I didn't check the detail of calculation):

$$z_G=\frac{\int_V z\cdot \rho(x,y,z)dV}{M}$$

Comment: How do you see that $\rho(x,y,z)$ is symmetric about the z-axis? Doesen't the $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ term mean that it also depends on $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: @Pame since $\rho(x,y,z)=\rho(-x,y,z)=\rho(x,-y,z)=\rho(-x,-y,z)$

Comment: @Pame or also note that for z=constant $\rho=\rho(r)$

Comment: Ok i see that it must be symmetric about the $z$-axis, but i don't quite get why it means the center of mass must lie on the $z$-axis.

Comment: @Pame consider $\int_V x\cdot \rho(x,y,z)dV$ and divede in two parts by y-z plane for x positive $V_1$ and x negative $V_2$ then 

$$\int_V x\cdot \rho(x,y,z)dV=\int_{V_1} x\cdot \rho(x,y,z)dV+\int_{V_2} x\cdot \rho(x,y,z)dV=\int_{V_1} x\cdot \rho(x,y,z)dV+\int_{V_2} -|x|\cdot \rho(-|x|,y,z)dV=\int_{V_1} x\cdot \rho(x,y,z)dV+\int_{V_1} -x\cdot \rho(x,y,z)dV=0$$

Comment: Ah, yes it makes more sense now. Shouldn't the mass integral also be $0$ though since you integrate 360 degrees about the $z$-axis and the function $\rho$ is symmetric about the $z$-axis? I don't see why everything changes because you multiply the integrand by $x$.

Comment: @Pame for the mass integral the integrand is positive thus $\int_V \rho(x,y,z)dV>0$ whereas for $x_G=\frac{\int_V x\cdot \rho(x,y,z)dV}{M}$ we have a term x wich makes one half integral positive and one half equal but negative thus the sum is zero.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the coordinates of the center of mass of the region $\Omega$ are given by

$$
\overline{{\bf x}} = \frac{\int_\Omega{\rm d}{\bf x}~{\bf x}\rho({\bf x})}{\int_\Omega{\rm d}{\bf x}~\rho({\bf x})} \tag{1}
$$

In your case $\Omega = \{(x,y,z) | x^2+y^2 < 1, 0 < z < \pi/2 \}$

We can then calculate

> $\int_\Omega{\rm d}{\bf x}~\rho({\bf x})$

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_\Omega{\rm d}{\bf x}~\rho({\bf x}) &=& \int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm dz}\int_0^1{\rm dR}~R\rho(R,\phi,z) \\
&=& \int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm dz}\int_0^1{\rm dR}~R [5(R + \sin z)] \\
&=& 10\pi \int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm dz}\int_0^1{\rm dR}~R (R + \sin z) \\
&=& (\dots)
\end{eqnarray}

> $\int_\Omega{\rm d}{\bf x}~x\rho({\bf x})$

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_\Omega{\rm d}{\bf x}~x\rho({\bf x}) &=& \int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm dz}\int_0^1{\rm dR}~Rx\rho(R,\phi,z) \\
&=& \int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm dz}\int_0^1{\rm dR}~R [R\cos\phi][5(R + \sin z)] 
&=& (\dots)
\end{eqnarray}

> $\int_\Omega{\rm d}{\bf x}~y\rho({\bf x})$

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_\Omega{\rm d}{\bf x}~y\rho({\bf x}) &=& \int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm dz}\int_0^1{\rm dR}~Ry\rho(R,\phi,z) \\
&=& \int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm dz}\int_0^1{\rm dR}~R [R\sin\phi][5(R + \sin z)] 
&=& (\dots)
\end{eqnarray}

> $\int_\Omega{\rm d}{\bf x}~z\rho({\bf x})$

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_\Omega{\rm d}{\bf x}~z\rho({\bf x}) &=& \int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm dz}\int_0^1{\rm dR}~Rz\rho(R,\phi,z) \\
&=& \int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm dz}\int_0^1{\rm dR}~R [z][5(R + \sin z)] 
&=& (\dots)
\end{eqnarray}

> Everything together

When you calculate these integrals, just use Eq. (1)